# Wagtail mock images show as broken in admin but visible on template

Tags: django, image-processing, wagtail

I have a demo Wagtail website. A site is generated via a Cookiecutter. To populate the CMS with initial content I have added a `load_initial_data` command that can be run once Wagtail is installed. This populates text content from a fixtures JSON file, and moves images from the fixtures folder to the Wagtail site's media_root folder. The code looks like:

```
# load_initial_data.py
import os, shutil

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management import call_command


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        fixtures_dir = os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_DIR, 'fixtures')
        fixture_file = os.path.join(fixtures_dir, 'db.json')
        image_src_dir = os.path.join(fixtures_dir, 'images')
        image_dest_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'original_images')

        call_command('loaddata', fixture_file, verbosity=0)

        if not os.path.isdir(image_dest_dir):
            os.makedirs(image_dest_dir)

        for filename in os.listdir(image_src_dir):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(image_src_dir, filename), image_dest_dir)
```

This works to the extent that the images are copied to the correct directory, and on the templates the images appear as expected when requested. The problem is within `/admin/images/` where the requested version of the image is unavailable, and so the browser shows a broken image icon.

The admin page is looking for a specific size of the image (`{your-image-name}.max-165x165.{.jpg|.png|.gif}`.

Watching how images move from `original_images` to `images` makes it appear that they are only processed after the template they are on is first requested. One idea then might be to create a template listing all the images (with the correct styling) to process them after the data has been loaded in. However doing something like

```
{% image page.image max-165x165 as test_photo %}
    <img src="{{ test_photo.url }}" width="{{ test_photo.width }}" height="{{ test_photo.height }}" alt="{{ test_photo.alt }}" />
```

Still returns a broken image, and doesn't process the image from the `original_images` folder to the `images` folder as I'd have expected. I tried this after the initial data load, and am presuming it's because the image size needs to have a reference within both the database and template?

Is there a way to programmatically force Wagtail to reprocess all the images to generate the size and file name that the image admin page is looking for?

(To mention quickly, if it's relevant, that the images currently sit within the project repo, but will ultimately be a zip file stored on a cloud store and only be imported to the project once requested. Currently, regardless of whether the user wants them or not, the images are included with the Cookiecutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a template (either front-end or within the admin) requires an image at a particular size, it will look in the `wagtailimages.Rendition` model (or the project-specific Rendition model, if custom image models are in use) to see if one has previously been generated. If so, it will use the existing file; if not, it will generate a new one and add a Rendition record.

If you're getting a broken image, it most likely means that a Rendition record exists (because it's been included in your initial data fixture) but the corresponding image file isn't present in MEDIA_ROOT/images. The proper fix would be to remove the rendition records from your fixture. To fix this after the fact and force all image renditions to be recreated, you can simply delete the contents of the `wagtailimages_rendition` table.

Comment: Thanks Gasman. Deleting any reference to the `wagtailimages.rendition` model within the fixtures JSON file fixed the problem. Thanks!